# PHP WordPress 'the_content' issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I probably have an easy issue here: I'm new to php and WordPress template development: in my php I get error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF)'

I basically created a page and added content there and want to display dynamically on my home page.

Code below:

```
 <?php
 /**
template name: Home Page
 */

get_header(); ?>

<!--HERO-->
    <section id="hero">

        <article>

            <div class="container-fluid clearfix">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>                 


                    <div class="col-lg-3" "hero-text">  
                        <p class="lead newfont"><?php the_content(); ?></p> 
                    </div><!--col-->

<?php endwhile; ?>              

            </div><!--container-->

        </article><!--article-->    

    </section><!--HERO-->

<?php

get_footer();
```

The error is somewhere in the the_content(); if statement. But not sure whats wrong tried going over the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/

Any tip is appreciated as I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened an if statement but you didn't close it at:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Just close it after closing the while loop:

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This should solve your problem. Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Thanks mate you actuully solved this one rookie mistake here, I have another question maybe you know the answer:                                          '<p class="lead newfont"><?php the_content(); ?></p>'  why the_content doesn't receive this class "lead newfont" as if I change the content to title, the page title displayed the right way. What basically happens this creates an new <p> element instead of adding content as it where it is in the code.

Comment: That's a CSS question, not PHP. Please post a new question providing the example code

Comment: no worries mate got it working:                                                         remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );

remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );